# cannot compile android app

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
package com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewActivity2.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

error missing class Activity Main and NewActivity2. both of these are in my manifest. the mainactivity.java file is above in its' entirety I am trying to add a second activity to my android app. there is of course a second java file for the other activity

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: please provide compilation error logs

Comment: Without any extra info and compilation logs my guess would be that you have issues with package names / imports.

Comment: <application
android:supportsRtl="true"
>
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".NewActivity2"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity" />

Comment: uploaded essence of manifest

Comment: @StevePaul Can you upload the exact error message too? That would be really helpful for us to understand the problem...

Comment: there are two error messages. first cannot find symbol class NewActivity2 and cannot find symbol class activity.main. I am not sure but suspect the problem is the manifest which is listed above